# Calabash how to select a value on a drop down select element in cordova app

Tags: cordova, cucumber, automated-tests, calabash

I have this script in my .rb step definition file

**touch("webView css:'select#MySelect'")**

but I cannot query the option element and cannot find a way to access it with calabash, any help?

when I query the select element I get the following

```
[
    [0] {
             "center" => {
            "X" => 384,
            "Y" => 321
        },
            "webView" => "<UIWebView: 0x7fcdd2421e90; frame = (0 0; 768 1024); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fcdd2456790>>",
           "nodeName" => "SELECT",
                 "id" => "ACTION_TYPE",
        "textContent" => "\n        \n      To DoPhone CallMeetingReminderOther",
              "class" => "",
               "rect" => {
                   "x" => 384,
              "height" => 40,
                   "y" => 321,
               "width" => 734,
                "left" => 17,
                 "top" => 301,
            "center_y" => 321,
            "center_x" => 384
        },
           "nodeType" => "ELEMENT_NODE"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

The element being rendered probably doesn't have the type option. Use query("webview css:'*'") to find all elements and try locating the element in your console using a simple search for text.

Comment: I tried that, I couldn't find option tags in the output, I appending options at run time, could that be the reason?

Comment: You should not look for the option tags in the output. As I mentioned, they are probably not rendered as option elements.

Answer (score 0):

On iOS, you should check out the xpath and JavaScript API.

https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/06-WebView-Support

There is also this sample app:

https://github.com/calabash/ios-webview-test-app

Comment: I did, I tried all possible CSS selectors to access option elements with no luck

Comment: As Tobias and I have mentioned, we think you can't use the CSS API.  You'll need to use the Xpath or JavaScript API.

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution

**js = "document.getElementsByTagName('option')[3].selected = 'selected'"
query("webView", {calabashStringByEvaluatingJavaScript: js})**

Comment: This is not a good solution. If a view is rendered, it is most likely in the DOM tree, and should be accessible by a css or xpath selector

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work, I am building this code for testing purpose to evaluation calabash as a testing framework for our App

Comment: Did you try using query("webview css:'*'") and look for your values manually? If not, try query("all webview css:'*'").